# Aligning list items with title

Tags: css

I'm trying to center and unordered list perfectly with the title of my website the title on top with the UL elements centered underneath.

The problem is that it does center, but not perfectly aligned with the overhead title. It is slightly to the right.

Here is my code:

```
.title{
  text-align: center;

}

nav{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; 
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: No HTML? There is your problem right there! CSS needs HTML for it to work .. :P

Comment: Also remove the default padding/margin that `ul` have.

Comment: Please provide your markup and also consider providing an example of the intended result.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

The slight right-side bias is because of the default padding the entire list gets, not the individual list items. Setting it to zero eliminates the unnecessary offset.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess the HTML, but most likely you have a `<ul>` inside your `<nav>` element. Use this CSS:

```
nav > ul { margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0; }
```